# Android Studio - How to upload files in webview Lollipop (Android 5.0)

Tags: android, file-upload, webview, android-studio, android-5.0-lollipop

I am using webview for my app, which is working good in Android Jelly Bean. The upload option is not working in Android KitKat and Lollipop.

I read some online forums and figured out that file upload is broken in KitKat version. So, I think that it would not work on KitKat.

But, I still want to know that how to call the file upload option in Android Lollipop in WebView.

Thanks

Comment: Could Anybody Help Me?

Also, I have target api to 15, so why doesn't kitkat and lollipop show the choose file dialog box when upload button is clicked. 

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The new api for Lollipop file upload is detailed here https://gauntface.com/blog/2014/10/17/what-you-need-to-know-about-the-webview-in-l

There is a full code sample here https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chromium-webview-samples/tree/master/input-file-example

Comment: Works only and only on Lollipop. No 5.0 below support.

Comment: For older versions : http://androidexample.com/Open_File_Chooser_With_Camera_Option_In_Webview_File_Option/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=128&aaid=148