# Android- File Uploading in Android 5.0+

Tags: android, webview

I am working on an app which consists of simple webview of my website and 
which will allow downloading and uploading files on my website

After spending hours on stackoverflow , I managed to get downloading working

However, I'm stuck at upload from 3 days

I followed this link([File Upload in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907369/file-upload-in-webview)) and tried every solution there .

Sadly none of them worked.(I probably did not put the code properly)
Can anyone tell me what i need to do ?? 
My app is specifically android 5.0+ and I'm unable to trace out the solution needed for android lollipop and above.

PS : I tried this also ([Android Studio - How to upload files in webview Lollipop (Android 5.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28315363/android-studio-how-to-upload-files-in-webview-lollipop-android-5-0)) but it also didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I found the solution
This works perfectly
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chromium-webview-samples/tree/master/input-file-example

I was a bit too lazy to search even more